# how to run ActiveX object on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to run code of javascript having ActiveX object on Mozilla firefox, can anyone tell me how to do

Answer (score 1):

[You can't.](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex) It's possible that you could [use Java to access the ActiveX object](http://www.drdobbs.com/184405738) though, but you would still be excluding Mac and Linux users.

Comment: Right! Why use just one failed client technology when you can use two at the same time. Just kidding. How is this going to work in the browser? Jacob needs access to Native code. That is not allowed in applets.

Answer (score 0):

The [official word](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex) is its not supported.

EDIT: On Windows you could try the IETab plugin. It just might work.